# ViewModel object attribute uninitialized?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, viewmodel

I sometimes get an error of `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` (from analytics), but the application has never crashed during my experience of using it. I think after application is dropped in background and process is killed then this happens - but I've no way of reproducing this error.

In my Activity, I do following:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.xxx)
    ... // doing other stuff
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.init(
            ...,
            ...,
            ...,))
    setUpObservables()
}
```

and my `MyViewModel` looks like:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

var lateinit car: String 

fun init(
        car: String,
        ...: String?,
        ...: Boolean 
) {
    if (isInitialized) {
        return
    }
    this.car = car
    ...

    isInitialized = true
}
```

Later on I try to access `car` object an get an error if it's uninitialized. Question is - how can this happen? `car` object is initialized when `MyViewModel` is. Any ideas how to reproduce this? Any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: Apart form the fact that is "lateinit var car: String" not "var lateinit..." ill give it a run but it looks fine to me

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I've added your code like this in a ViewModel on one of my working projects.

```
lateinit var car: String

fun init(car: String) {
    this.car = car
}
```

And called:

```
viewModel.init("car")
Log.d("CAR_DEBUG",viewModel.car)
```

And received in my console the expected output:  **D/CAR_DEBUG: car**. So it works but bugs might appear depending on your implementation.

Also, this is not the correct way to do this, I would suggest using the MutableLiveData observer pattern so that you make sure that any unexpected behaviour won't happen due to screen rotation or activity/fragment recreation. With this in mind change your code to this:

```
var carObservable: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

fun init(car: String) {
    carObservable.value = car
}
```

And in Activity/Fragment:

```
viewModel.carObservable.observe(this, Observer {
    Log.d("CAR_DEBUG",it)
})
// doesnt matter where your viewModel.init this will still work
viewModel.init("car")
```

This way even if you call the init function after the observe invocation you are sure that you are notified only when the value changes. This is actually the recommended way of using ViewModels (the reactive way through the observer pattern). And doing this you make sure that even if you rotate the screen or recreate the Activity/Fragment your car variable will be available.